# Inno Setup [Code] section variable to [Registry]

Tags: inno-setup

I have a problem with Inno Setup.

I'm using resolution detection script in `[Code]` section from here:
[INNO Setup: How to get the primary monitor's resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5461674/inno-setup-how-to-get-the-primary-monitors-resolution)

And now I want to put `xres` and `yres` values to `[Registry]` section of my installer which looks like this.

```
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\MyApp\Settings"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueType: dword; \
    ValueName: "ScreenWidth"; ValueData: "XRES"
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\MyApp\Settings"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueType: dword; \
    ValueName: "ScreenHeight"; ValueData: "YRES"
```

I tried this method [How to use a Pascal variable in Inno Setup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757284/how-to-use-a-pascal-variable-in-inno-setup), but I can't get it work. I tried to solve the problem by myself many times, but I give up...

Can someone help me and explain how to do that?
I'm newbie with Inno Setup, and especially with Pascal.

Comment: Out of interest, why can't the application get this information itself? After all, it may change by the time the application is run, or at any time after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way can be writing a single [`scripted constant`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants) function for both dimensions and by the passed parameter return either horizontal or vertical resolution. The rest is upon Inno Setup engine:

```
[Setup]
AppName=My Program
AppVersion=1.5
DefaultDirName={pf}\My Program

[Registry]
; the GetResolution function used in the following {code:...} scripted constants
; takes as parameter X to retrieve horizontal resolution, Y to retrieve vertical
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\MyApp\Settings"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueType: dword; \
   ValueName: "ScreenWidth"; ValueData: "{code:GetResolution|X}"
Root: HKCU; Subkey: "Software\MyApp\Settings"; Flags: uninsdeletekey; ValueType: dword; \
    ValueName: "ScreenHeight"; ValueData: "{code:GetResolution|Y}"
```

```pascal
[Code]
function GetSystemMetrics(nIndex: Integer): Integer;
  external 'GetSystemMetrics@user32.dll stdcall';

const
  SM_CXSCREEN = 0;
  SM_CYSCREEN = 1;

function GetResolution(Param: string): string;
begin
  // in the {code:...} constant function call we are passing either
  // X or Y char to its parameter (here it is the Param parameter),
  // so let's decide which dimension we return by the Param's first
  // char (uppercased to allow passing even small x and y)
  case UpperCase(Param[1]) of
    'X': Result := IntToStr(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN));
    'Y': Result := IntToStr(GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: P.S. don't forget to uninstall the previous instance of your setup since the settings used in your entries won't overwrite existing values in registry when you install another instance.