# Using function return value in Inno Setup [Registry]

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Is there anyway to have the return value of a function for the `ValueData` (or similar property). Tried the following:

```
Root: HKLM; \
   Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; \
   ValueType: string; ValueName: "Hostname"; ValueData: GetComputerNameString(); \
   Flags: preservestringtype;
```

But this simply adds the string `GetComputerNameString()` to the registry item.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [scripted constant](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptconstants), with syntax `{code:FunctionName}`. Though the scripted constant function must take a string parameter (even if the actual implementation does not need any parameter). So the `GetComputerNameString` is not compatible. You have to create a proxy function.

```
[Registry]
Root: HKLM; \
    Subkey: "SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment"; \
    ValueType: string; ValueName: "Hostname"; ValueData: {code:GetComputerName}; \
    Flags: preservestringtype;
```

```pascal
[Code]

function GetComputerName(Param: string): string;
begin
  Result := GetComputerNameString;
end;
```

---

For a more complex example, see [Inno Setup [Code] section variable to [Registry]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25372103/850848).